# Is it good to create a nonclustered index on a column of type varchar?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which I have created a clustered index in one of the column of type `INT`. I wanted to create a nonclustered index to increase the performance of the query. However, I do not have any column of type `int`.

I therefore thought of creating a nonclustered index on a `varchar` type column.

Will it be good to create an index on a column of type `Varchar`? Will it help improving the performance of a query? I know it is not a good thing to create an index on a `varchar` type column, but just wanted to know if it will improve query performance.

Comment: "I know it is not a good thing to create an index on a varchar type column"  Where did you see that?

Comment: Good? It depends on your queries. If you are not going to use the index, no, it is no good.

Comment: If you want to find out if the index will improve things, you need to test. Check the query plan before the change and after the change (dropping statistics in between so you compare like to like). I suggest watching this: [Back to Index Basics: How to Make SELECT Statements Faster (Video)](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/10/back-index-basics-how-make-select-statements-faster-video/).

Comment: As long as the column is less than 900 bytes long, and is being used in a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause of a frequently executed query - I don't see any reason why a nonclustered index should be bad. A large `varchar` column certainly makes for a rather bad **clustered** index (because of large size and because of varying length) - but those issues don't apply to the **nonclustered** indexes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is nothing whatever wrong with creating an index on a VARCHAR column, or set of columns.

Regarding the performance of VARCHAR/INT, as with everything in a RDBMS, it depends on what you are doing. What you may be thinking of is the fact that clustering a table on a VARCHAR key is (in SQL Server) marginally less efficient than clustering on a monotonically increasing numerical key, and can introduce fragmentation.

Or you may be thinking of what you have heard about writing JOINs on VARCHAR columns - it is true, it is a little less efficient than a JOIN on numeric type, but it is only a little less efficient, nothing that would lead you to never join on varchar cols.

None of this does not mean that you should not create indexes on VARCHAR columns. A needed index on a VARCHAR column will boost query performance, often by orders of magnitude. If you need an index on a VARCHAR, create it. It makes no sense to try to find an integer column to create the index on - the engine will never use it.